# Delete instance of inner class in an instance of outer class

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, instance, destructor

Suppose I have a class `Inner` within another class  `Outer`:

```
class Inner
{
public:
    Inner();
    ~Inner();
};

class Outer
{
public:
    Outer();
    ~Outer();
private:
    Inner in;
};
```

Now say in main I declare an object of type Outer:

```
int main()
{
    Outer out;

    return 0;
}
```

The object `out` has an instance of `in` as a member. If I call the destructor of `out`, will it in turn call the destructor of `in`? If not, how can I implement the destructor for the class `Outer` to successfully invoke the destructor of the class `Inner`?

For example, if I have an application of users, and each user has a profile, how can I make it so when a user's account is deleted, so is the user's profile?

Comment: The destructor for `in` will be called.  It wouldn't be called if `in` was an `inner*` and was declared using `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `class Outer`'s instance `out` goes out of scope the first thing that happens is all of its members (which have also just gone out of scope) have their destructors called.  Then `class Outer`'s destructor is called. The C++ standard guarantees this so this behavior is generated automatically by your C++ compiler.